# How to get the dump/export of outlook's address book using UI-path or without UI-path?

Tags: outlook, uipath, uipath-activity

I want to export all people from my address book to excel using UI-path. If possible or is there any other way to get the export of the outlook address book.

Comment: I hate to be 'that guy' but probably not a good idea to export into an excel for GDPR protocols etc. Is there a reason to put it into Excel?

Comment: Yes, there is a reason - I have a list of people(a dump of SharePoint list). where I would like to map the list (which I already have) with the outlook address book dump. Finally, non-matching email ids need to be flagged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can develop a VBA macro which can do the job for you. The [NameSpace.AddressLists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.addresslists?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm759);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) property returns an `AddressLists` collection representing a collection of the address lists available for this session. The `AddressLists` collection represents the root of the address book hierarchy for the current session. A particular `AddressList` object represents one of the available address books.

```
Set myAddressList = Application.Session.AddressLists("Personal Address Book")
```

You may find the following articles helpful:

- [Getting started with VBA in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office)
- [Using Visual Basic for Applications in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/using-visual-basic-for-applications-in-outlook)